# How to use namespace in ROS?

Tags: ros

I can not understand how the namespace works in ROS http://wiki.ros.org/Names
Can you hang a couple of real examples of how this works?

And the same question on the parameters http://wiki.ros.org/Parameter%20Server
What do these names mean?
Are the names of the package-node-parameter or what?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Namespaces are the best option to deal with name collision which is quite oft in robotics, especially when the system is going bigger and more complex...

Imagine you have a robot with 2 sensors for the distance, the front and back, then you can think I have 2 topics with the same info
**distance=10** and **distance=10**

now what? how can a 3rd node knows which distance is which???

now using namespaces you can avoid that issue by just doing

**back/distance=10** and **front/distance=10**